# flaws in second's field increment in stop watch

Tags: javascript, html

```
<script>
var s=0;
var ms=0;
function timeDisp()
{
 var d = new Date();
 ms = d.getMilliseconds();

  if(ms==999 && s<60)
  {
    s=s+1;
    ms=0;
  }

var r = (((s <10)?"0":":") + s + (":") + ms);
return r;
}

function display() 
{
 var t = timeDisp();
 document.getElementById("time").value=t;   //time is id of input text field
 m=setTimeout('display()',1);
}

function stop()
{
 clearTimeout(m);
}
</script>
```

I have written this code to create simple stop watch but there is flaw in increment in seconds field.Sometimes second do not increase as it should and sometime it skip one or two seconds while running.

Comment: You are attempting to run this every 1 ms but it probably wont actually run that frequently, so you can't be sure that *getMilliseconds* will ever return 999 except by chance. Use the seconds and milliseconds from the Date, don't decrement some other value.

Comment: That code relies on display() being called every millisecond. That does not necessarily happen, it might take 1.01 milliseconds to call, and those microseconds add up quickly. You should take ALL fields from that Date-object, and just update them on-screen.